# Spring Security ACL - can users with READ permission revoke their own access?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

We are using Spring ACL over our domain objects. I have a use case where users can be given READ permissions on objects, but we want these users to also be able to revoke their own permissions (i.e. remove their own, and only their own, authorisation on the object).

I have been looking at the Spring [Run-As](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/runas.html) documentation. Would this be the best path to follow? At the moment, I am getting caught in the AclAuthorisationStrategy secutity check requiring admin permission for this change when I call the deleteAce method in the Acl implementation (using the default `AclImpl` implementation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path you should follow is to implement your own `org.springframework.security.acls.domain.AclAuthorizationStrategy` strategy that will meet your requirements. Then inject your implementation into `org.springframework.security.acls.domain.AclImpl` or whatever ACL implementation you use.